# How can i display this.state value in save.js?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, block, wordpress-gutenberg

i'm new to react and wanna ask how i can display `this.state` values in my wordpress frontend? (save.js)

edit.js:

```
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';

const { Component } = wp.element;
const { Spinner } = wp.components;
 
class Edit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: [],
            loading: true,
            test: 'lorem ipsum'
        }
    }
 
    componentDidMount() {
        this.runApiFetch();
    }
 
    runApiFetch() {
        apiFetch({ path: '/wp/v2/posts' })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    list: data,
                    loading: false
                })
        })
    }
 
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.loading ? (
                    <Spinner />
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {this.state.list.map(post => {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    { post.title.rendered }
                                </div>  
                            )
                        }) }
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Edit;
```

save in my index.js:

```
save() {
    const { test } = this.state;

    return (
        <>  
            <div>{test}</ div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I got this error:

[image]

How i can display this.state values in wordpress frontend? Everything works in editor view.

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` function in save.js cannot access the internal state contained within `Edit` causing the error seen.

As you're new to React, I'd suggest starting your project with the [WordPress Create Block tool](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block) which will make starting a project easier and setup a solid foundation to build from.

WordPress Gutenberg blocks are built differently compared to a straight ReactJS project and what you'd assume to be the 'state' is stored in the attributes, defined in `block.json` so its accessible between the `edit()` and `save()` functions. The `edit()` function is what is displayed in the Editor to the User, where the `save()` function in a static block is the content saved and rendered to the front end. So if you were displaying a list of posts in the Editor with [apiFetch](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/) that was the "latest" or some other attribute that changes, you would store the parameters required in the [block attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/) then dynamically render the block on the frontend using those parameters in the block attributes.